# How to have powershell email upon failure or success of connection to sftp

Tags: powershell

Below is a modified example of a script (from winscp) that connects to a remote sftp site and downloads the latest file to one of my local servers.

I would like to have this script email our distribution if it fails to connect to the SFTP or can't find a file. Is this possible at all? We are running Office 365 but also have a local SMTP server.

```
param (
    $localPath = "\\70.70.49.20\d$\Reports\GILL",
    $remotePath = "/home/temp/"
)

try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = "73.89.10.17"
        UserName = "Username"
        Password = "Password"
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 5d:cd:8d:d9:df:d3:db:dd:ed:fd:8d:ed:cd:d2:fd:9d"
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Get list of files in the directory
        $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

        # Select the most recent file
        $latest =
            $directoryInfo.Files |
            Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1

        # Any file at all?
        if ($latest -eq $Null)
        {
            Write-Host "No file found"
            exit 1
        }

        # Select latest folder in localpath
        $folder = Get-ChildItem '\\70.70.49.20\d$\Reports\GILL' | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -Descending | select -First 1

        # Download the selected file
        $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $latest.Name), $localPath + $folder.Name + "\Spots\").Check()
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host ("Error: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Just put your code to send the mail in the catch block so it triggers when an error occurs in your try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in catch block

```
Send-MailMessage -To 'DL@MyDomain.com' -From 'SFTConnector@MyDomain.com' -Subject 'SFTP connection failed' -SmtpServer mail.mydomain.com
```

You may configure it according to your needs. Read more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)

Another question/suggestion. I would try to avoid nested try/catch/finally blocks. Try to build script logic in order to avoid it and put one after another, not one inside of another.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Also this was mostly copied from the WinSCP site for their PS script solution and this is the first time I've seen PS script written this way....so when you said add a "Catch Block" I had to look that up.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code some where before the try and just call the function inside try and catch with different messages:

```
$Username = "MyUserName";
$Password= "MyPassword";

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string]$attachmentpath){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "YourName@gmail.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "subject text here...";
    $message.Body = "body text here...";
    $attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentpath);
    $message.Attachments.Add($attachment);

    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message);
    write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
    $attachment.Dispose();
}

Send-ToEmail  -email "reciever@gmail.com" -attachmentpath $path;
```